# almost same code. but the other one does not produce an output in returning a child function

Tags: javascript, return, closures

I am studying closures in Javascript and I saw this code example for closure  with an output of integer "2"

```
function foo() {
    var a = 2;

    function bar() {
        console.log( a );
    }
    return bar;
}

var baz = foo();
baz();
```

And I try to modify it to see if i can see a same result by removing the var baz which function foo(); is passed, to reduce the code cause i think it has the same logic. But after changing it, it does not give me any output. Here is the code

```
function foo() {
    var a = 2;

    function bar() {
        console.log( a );
    }
    return bar;
}

foo();
```

I was expecting to see the same result. since var baz is referencing the foo() function then why not remove the var baz and just execute the foo(); function. but i didnt give any output at all. can someone enlighten me what happens here?

Comment: `foo()()` to invoke the returned function immediately. To do it with only `foo()`, you'd need to put `console.log(a)` directly in `foo` without a wrapping function.

Comment: *"...since var baz is referencing the foo() function"* It's not. It's referencing the value that was returned from invoking `foo()`, which is the `bar` function. In your first example... `console.log(baz.name); // "bar"`

Comment: @squiant you might misunderstood my question. cause my english is real bad, but what I'm confused is that when i remove the variable baz, i didnt give me the expected output. even though I already calls the foo() function

Comment: I understand the question. Doing `foo()` invokes the `foo` function. That function returns the `bar` function. The `console.log()` won't run until you invoke the function that was returned. That's why it works when you do `baz()`, because `baz` is holding a reference to the `bar` function that was returned.

Comment: Do this: `console.log(baz.toString())`... you'll see it print out the `bar` function. So `baz` is *holding* the `bar` function, and you invoke it with `baz()`.

Comment: @squint oh  I see it cleary now! since it just returning a function doesn't mean it execute the block of code inside that bar() function. and when baz() executes. it run all the function connected to it.! thank you so much!

Comment: Yep, exactly. Passing around functions like any other object is a little strange at first, but is very useful once you get the hang of it.

Comment: @squint by doing console.log(baz.toString()) i see all the bar() function in string form. but why i didnt see any properties of foo() in string form too?since they are all connected

Comment: Nope, they're not at all connected. The `foo` function simply returned it. Imagine if `foo()` returned an Array instead `return []`, and you logged that to the console. Would you expect to see any reference to `foo` on the  Array?

Comment: no,  I can see the light now :) foo() is just like tossing the bar() for baz().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the difference between **calling** and **not calling** a function. Indeed doing

```
var baz = foo();
```

stores the call**able** named `bar` in the variable `baz`. Then doing

```
baz()
```

**calls/invokes** it.

Actually, as outlined by squint, you can directly *call the callable* `bar` returned by the function `foo` via doing

```
foo()()
```

#### more details

Consider the function `foo` you defined. As such, `foo` can also be considered/used as a callable. If I do

```
var fou = foo;
```

Then I can call the function `foo` contained in the variable `fou` by doing

```
var baz = fou();
```

Henceforth, the callable `bar` is contained in the variable `baz`.

Comment: you mean variable baz is the one invoking the bar function? not foo() function?

Comment: @Makopa. Actually i mean that the variable `baz` (which contains the callable `bar` since this is what the function foo returns when called) is the one which can, if you wish, invoke the `bar` function: via doing `baz()`. Note that a synonymous of "callable", using the term "invoke" would be invokable.

Comment: thanks!! I need to call baz() function by doing foo()(); or by executing the bar() function inside function foo {....}

Comment: @Makopa. Actually, this depends on what you need and where you need it. If you need the output returned by calling the function `bar` inside the function `foo`, you may want to call it inside of it. It you need your function to return, say, a different callable (`bar` sometime or `bar2`, etc) given an exogenous condition, you may want not to call it inside. Actually, this depends totally on what you want to do.

Comment: @Makopa. Note that from an optimization point of view, it may not be a good idea to define the function `bar` inside the function `foo`, since each time you call `foo`, you also redefine on the fly the function `bar`. Instead, a better approach would be defining `bar` before the definition of `foo`, but still making `foo` return the callable `bar` when needed.

Comment: about that optimization you mean. create the bar() function outside the foo() function and then call it inside the function foo() { bar(); } i tried it works :>

Comment: @Makopa. It is not linked to the fact it works or to calling it, but instead to performance stuffs. As you can imagine, given that the definition of `bar` is inside `foo`, each time you call `foo` you also redefine `bar`. You must have very good reasons to do so.

Comment: ya! I understand. its like saving memory for the compiler so every time i run the foo() function. compiler don't need to redo the bar function again. I definitely need to check lesson about the practices for optimization. thaks for the headsup advice! appreciated!